# getting Error=redirect_uri_mismatch from google trying to exchange auth_code for access_token using django-rest-auth

Tags: django, google-api, django-rest-framework, registration, django-rest-auth

I am building a rest api that gets authorization code from Android app and send id to google to exchange IT for Access  token. It aims to provide registration with google. I am using for it two libraries:

```
djangorestframework-oauth==1.1.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.1
```

This is implementation of my login/register class

```
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
client_class = OAuth2Client
callback_url = 'http://localhost:8000/v1/accounts/google/login/callback/'
```

I set everything in

> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=testserwusapp

I created Id client 0Auth for web applicatio. I added

```
http://localhost:8000
```

to authorized javascript sourced  and

```
http://localhost:8000/v1/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

to  Authorized redirect URI.

I tried many variations of those links. Both with slash and without slash in the end.

I set both client id and client secret key in my django app. However, I get `Error=redirect_uri mismatch` trying to exchange auth_code for access_code.

What is more I tried to use ngrok to publish my ip. I though that maybe google won't work with `localhost` but it didn't help.

Comment: Any progress on this one? I have configured that with my domain in the same setup but it didn't work.